# How to count an occurance of a specific value in each partition?

Tags: t-sql

I need to count the occurance of -1 value for every partition of a table. If a partition contains only two rows I could use min,max functions but for partitions with more than two rows it's not a solution.

```
CREATE TABLE #Data(ID int,name_of_institution varchar(200),wasko_id int)


INSERT INTO #Data(ID,name_of_institution,wasko_id)


SELECT 4822,'Bailiff xxx',-1 union all

SELECT 4820,'Bailiff xxx',-1 union all

SELECT 4819,'Bailiff xxx',2332 union all

 SELECT 4700,'Bailiff yyy',-1 union all

SELECT 4701,'Bailiff yyy',222 


select DENSE_RANK() over (order by name_of_institution) as DR,* from #Data
```

I expect the output of 2 for 'Bailiff xxx' partition and 1 for 'Bailiff yyy' partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an excel like sumif: Sum of a conditional insert, where on True you sum 1 and on False you sum 0: `iif(condition, 1, 0)`

```
select name_of_institution, sum(iif(wasko_id = -1, 1, 0)) as DR 
from #Data 
group by name_of_institution
```